# error in SQL syntax; check manual corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'div='aa' WHERE Roll_No=2' at line 1

Tags: java, mysql

Error In Connection Due Tocom.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Div='aa' WHERE Roll_No=2' at line 1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggTca.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Div` is a reserved word, it should be quoted.

Using double quotes, note that they must be escaped because they are inside a Java String which is delimited by doubles quotes:

```java
"UPDATE Student SET Name=?,Std=?,\"Div\"=? WHERE Roll_No=?";
```

Or using backticks:

```java
"UPDATE Student SET Name=?,Std=?,`Div`=? WHERE Roll_No=?";
```

See the list of reserved words at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reserved-words/

As you're a student, let me give you a friendly advice: it's a good practice to give full names to your columns rather than abbreviations (e.g. `Division` rather than `Div`), this will improve readability and decreases the probability to run into reserved words.

Comment: But even if I write the place of Div in the name of another field, also getting error

Comment: String update = "UPDATE Student SET Name=?,Std=?,'Div'=? WHERE Roll_No=?";
This is My Update Query Please Solve my error

Comment: Answer edited, use double quotes or backticks.